# Remove text from String between characters which appear more than once

Tags: apex, string

I have a String value from a Long Text field that contains Name/Email values. I need to extract only the names separated by a semi colon when there are multiple entries (no semi colon in the text if only one name) using Apex/String methods into another variable. Essentially strip out anything that begins with the pipe delimiter ' | ' and ends with '.com' (will always end in '.com').

**Single value scenario:** 
John Test | jtest@none.com

**Expected:**
John Test

**Multiple values scenario:**
Scott Rogers | srogers@none.com; Mike Smith | msmith@none.com; Matt White | mwhite@none.com

**Expected:**
Scott Rogers; Mike Smith; Matt White

I've tried using substring/left/right but my approach may not be correct as I'm getting a null value each time and I also believe I need an array/list to grab each entry if multiple matches.

```
String s1 = 'Scott Rogers | srogers@none.com; Mike Smith | msmith@none.com; Matt White | mwhite@none.com';

String s2 = s1.right(1).substringBetween(' |','.com');
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [`split`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method twice, first on the semicolon and then on the pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two splits which will work for both single set and multiple values.

Also remember to use `\\` as `|` gets treated as special character.

```
String str = 'John Test | jtest@none.com';

List<String> strings = str.split(';');
for(String eachString : strings){
    System.debug(eachString);
    List<String> nameSplits = eachString.split('\\|');
    System.debug(nameSplits.get(0).removeStart(' '));
}
```

output:

```
09:46:42.13 (14393997)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|John Test
```

---

```
String str = 'Scott Rogers | srogers@none.com; Mike Smith | msmith@none.com; Matt White | mwhite@none.com';

List<String> strings = str.split(';');
for(String eachString : strings){
    List<String> nameSplits = eachString.split('\\|');
    System.debug(nameSplits.get(0).removeStart(' '));
}
```

output:

```
09:47:29.7 (8706488)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|Scott Rogers
09:47:29.7 (8760453)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|Mike Smith
09:47:29.7 (8794915)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|Matt White
```

Comment: Thank you very much!